# Add Duplicates keys to NameValueCollection

Tags: c#, .net, namevaluecollection

I have read that NameValueCollection allows for duplicate keys to be added, however this does not seem to be the case when I try to use it.

My Code

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
{
     var data = new NameValueCollection();
     var sourceData = (List<Dictionary<string, object>>)dic["mapData"];
     var countSource = sourceData.Count;

     foreach (var item in (List<Dictionary<string, object>>)dic["mapData"])
     {
          data.Add("pp", item["Latitude"].ToString() + "," + item["Longitude"].ToString());
     }

     var dataCount = data.Count;
     var response = wb.UploadValues(@"http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Imagery/Map/road/?mapArea=" + swLat.ToString() + "," + swLong + "," + neLat + "," + neLong + "&mapSize=800,600&key=" + key, "POST", data);

     return this.LargeJson(new { imageData = CreateBase64Image(response) });
}
```

What I am observing

my sourceData contains 36 items

[image: watches]

I am iterating through sourceData and adding items to my NameValueCollection data and add items with the same key "pp"

I was expecting to have 36 items in my data NameValueCollection, but I am only getting 1 and all of my values get appended to the same key.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour - see [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsc9a449.aspx):

> If the specified key already exists in the target NameValueCollection
>   instance, the specified value is added to the existing comma-separated
>   list of values in the form "value1,value2,value3". The values are
>   associated with the same key in the target NameValueCollection
>   instance.

Comment: This is the expected behavior. A dictionary is essentially a souped-up hashtable. The key values have to be unique.

Comment: What if the value contains commas?  For example, I can make a Uri like: `http://example.com/q?value=a%2Cb&value=b%2Cc`.  The values would be decoded as `a,b` and `b,c`, and if you slap them together they'll end up as `a,b,b,c`.  This cannot work this way. There should be a strong warning that use of duplicate keys implies that your values cannot contain commas, otherwise there will be an irreversible loss of well-defined boundaries between parameter values.  If NameValueCollection was implemented properly, it would maintain values with identical names in an array, not a comma-separated string.